# How to modify login.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I'm a newbie to CakePHP and i'm trying to modify the login.ctp so that it would go to a different DIV tag. I already have a default.ctp layout placed in /views/layout but i don't want the menus to appear on the login page when you bring up the site. How do i go about doing it?

Thanks,
Lyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a login layout that has no menu, and in login(), set `$this->layout= 'login';`

Comment: this is my login.ctp saved on /views/elements/

<ul>
 <div id="login" >
  <?php
   echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
   echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
   echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => __('<h1>Login!</h1>'),
    'username',
    'password'
   ));
   echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('id'=>'search-submit'));
  ?>
 </div>
</ul>

Shall i make another layout and save it somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: that's not the layout, that's the view of the action login(). Check here about the layout: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1080/Layouts And why do you have the login.ctp in elements folder?

Answer (score 1):

in login function, save variable:

```
$this->set('nomenus', true);
```

in default.ctp check

```
if( empty($nomenus) ) {
    ... menus ...
}
```